# Is this social engineering on facebook?

Tags: social-engineering, facebook

Today, I received a mail from fb saying that two of my friends have mentioned me in a comment. When I opened fb to see that comment, it was filled with random names (which obviously were their friends/friend-of-friends) and mine was one of them.

And the topic of the comment was an advertisement proclaiming a hack to reveal any fb user's username and password. It then gave a bunch of instructions asking you to visit the user's page, opening the browser web-console and pasting some code there. It claimed that doing so would reveal the said user's fb username and password (which is obviously absurd).

fb username of this topic poster was Beauty.20000. But whats going on here? Is this an attempt at social engineering (as I suspect) ?

Comment: Its a hack that you do and when you do it it tags all your friends

Comment: It's definitely some sort of social-engineering attack, yes.  You're doing XSS to yourself...  We'd need to see the code to know exactly what it would do, but I can guess that 1) It can likely trivially retrieve your username (not a _terribly_ big deal, on its own), and 2) no, it's unlikely to be able to just grab your password, so long as you don't enter it again.  It's possible that the given code has methods to persist over changes in the Facebook JavaScript code, so a simple logout may not be safe (you'd need to clear the browser cache).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I haven't done any XSS to myself, but looks like two of my friends have. Here is the code link which the poster provided: http://textuploader.com/rwf2/raw

Comment: Yeah, somebody's up to something, that's obfuscated.  I don't know enough to proceed easily myself, curious if somebody else here will do the honors.

Comment: Yup, way too obfuscated. Whilst I've coded in trivial javascript myself, this doesn't look like its hand-coded by anyone. Moreover, whats the point of obfuscation in social engineering anyway?

Comment: it's linked to 2 facebook accounts, 100000066374374 and 100002623931816, and a third 100006952119048 (obtained by deobfuscating the hex part with http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/), that doesn't exist anymore. 
That's all i can say since i don't know enough to decode all that fast. First guess is the same as @Clockwork-Muse's : XSS. But i couldn't spot any external url so it may send your information (cookies and stuff) to one of these accounts (or one that i missed).
Also curious =)

Comment: forgot 100000821542260 

@PrahladYeri : obfuscation helps a lot in SE! But here you are right, if the user does follow the instructions, he is dumb enough to do anything he's told...

PS: see the number of followers/likes on the 100000066374374 profile. Haha. There goes the answer i guess.

Comment: @Neckxt: You are right. This user 100000066374374 seems to have gotten lots of friends overnight (some of whom are in my circles). So this was an SE attempt by this user to get an astronomical amount of friends overnight and thus be popular? Does this really happen?

Comment: If you speak about XSS/XSRF: yes, it does happen a lot, everywhere on the net. But big social media sites are now protected against stored XSS since Samy ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_(XSS) ). but here the real problem is facebook users: they blindly trust what they read, and there's nothing you can do to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it certainly is. you might want to google "Phishing".

edit: i'm curious, what code did they ask to paste in the web console?

Comment: Updated the link to code in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is known as "self-XSS" or "self cross-site scripting".

Some websites now show a warning in the console:

[image]

Any code you paste here can be executed on the current page. If you're logged into Facebook, whoever wrote the code that you paste has full control over the current page.